# Return a pointer to pointers in a function

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I have a matrix in one class. That matrix is allocated dinamically,  I want to encapsulate it.

Here is my matrix declaration in the Header file:

```
float** matrix;
```

And here is the declaration of get method:

```
float *getMatrix();
```

Is everything correct so far?

I don't know how to work with pointers in that case. How would the get function look like?

Comment: _"Is everything correct so far?"_ Correct for achieving what exactly please?

Comment: [A Beginner's Guide to Pointers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627/A-Beginner-s-Guide-to-Pointers)

Comment: And please don't mix c with c++.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ : I want to know if the declaration of the get function is correct.

Comment: How are we supposed to know?

Answer (score 3):

if you want just to return matrix you should use

```
float** getMatrix();
```