# How to declare a function that returns a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a matrix in one class. That matrix is allocated dinamically,  I want to encapsulate it.

Here is my matrix declaration in the Header file:

```
float** matrix;
```

The declaration of get method should be like:

```
float *getMatrix();
```

Or like:

```
float **getMatrix();
```

I'm not familizarized with pointers.

Comment: Well, the type of `matrix` is `float**`, so if you want to return a matrix, the return type has to be `float**`. It's that simple. However, you shouldn't use pointers, use `std::vector` instead. It will me much simpler.

Comment: You have asked the same question two days ago: [Return a pointer to pointers in a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759708/return-a-pointer-to-pointers-in-a-function). And you have received an answer with a positive rating to it.

Answer (score 1):

By using the second method you described, the function will return a pointer.  It is irrelevant that the actual structure is a 2D array, a simple pointer can be incremented in two "dimensions" as long as the data in that space makes sense.

Further reading: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_to_an_array.htm

EDIT:  Also, as stefan mentioned above, std::Vectors are awesome unless a school assignment disallows them.